# Moving from Gulp to the Bundler and Minifier Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, bundling-and-minification, sizzle

we're attempting to move away from Gulp and instead using the integrated VS bundler and compiler extension.  It generates the output files of site.js and vendor.js fine, but when you reload the page, we get a [uncaught error](http://freetexthost.com/egkdqf4zua) in the vendor.js file, which is odd, as the gulp version (which doesn't give us the error) of vendor.js is identical.  I then thought this may be something to do with sizzlejs (included in the jquery version (1.11.3) we're using, but I couldn't debug it or know where to start and then I removed (from the gulpbuild) the uglify-js package and I now get the same error on gulp as I do with the new non-gulp build, so do I assume it's something to do with uglify? ...

Any help or thoughts really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out, but I'll add to here for anyone else that may have the problem.

Quite simply really, one of the bundled folders had 2 vendor js files exactly the same for some very odd reason. :-)

Comment: I only get issues if I copy/paste files within the same folder otherwise its works well..